# JavaScript class property cannot be found

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code. I am very new to JavaScript, and I have an error in:

```
class X {
    constructor() {
      this.pick = -1;
      this.isClosed = false;
      this.pline = [];
    }

  add(mx, my) {
    pline.push(Point(mx,my));
  }
  
  draw() { 
    beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < pline.length; i++) {
        p = pline[i];
        vertex( p.x, p.y );
    }
    ... //ignore the rest for now
```

the issue I am getting is: X, line 14:ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pline

I am a little confused because I am initializing it as a class property, so I am not sure why it cannot be found in the draw function. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: its hidden as an class property... try to change from `pline` to `this.pline`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have scoped pline to `this`, so it must be `this.pline.push`.

Also, if you want to use this scope, it's best to use arrow function methods to maintain the scope. Example:

```
class clazz{
    constructor() {
        this.something = 1;
    }
    
    add = () => {
        
        console.log(this.something);
        
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pline` refers to a variable (either local or global), not a property. If you want to access a property, then you must use `this.pline`. Although variables and properties seem the same, under the hood they are fairly different because of how JavaScript classes work (which is quite different from most languages).

Answer (score 1):

in your add() function you are referring to  "pline.push()", you need to use `this.pline.push()`